# can anyone explain the installation procedure to install webkit and gtk3 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python-2.7, webkit, pygtk, gtk3

We are trying to install webkit and Gtk in ubuntu 14.04. There are no clear explanation of how to install it in ubuntu .Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal application and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev
```

Then click <kbd>Enter</kbd> and type your password. Then click <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time.

Comment: That throws an error "Couldn't find package libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev"